# jQuery: Multiple buttons Toggle multiple classes (filtering) with localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage, toggle

I'm trying to create buttons that can show/hide multiple divs, and I also want to use localStorage to remember one's filtering (which buttons are clicked and which aren't).

I found [this](https://jsfiddle.net/undm500w/8/) jsfiddle and am trying to adapt it to my purposes. 
[Here is my jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zw813mpq/5/). I would really appreciate help updating this jsfiddle to get it to work properly:

1. localStorage no longer works; when I refresh page, the state is not remembered. (it did on the original jsfiddle). I want localStorage to remember which divs are hidden and retain the red "danger" button class
2. If no buttons are clicked: show all divs (working fine)
3. If one sport button is clicked, only show that sport's divs (check, but only for one sport right now)
4. If multiple sports buttons are clicked, show only those sports that are toggled. Hide others that are not toggled. (my head is spinning on how to get this to work. not sure how to get the different toggles to check with each other to see which ones are toggled or not)
5. Button is grey when not toggled, red when toggled (i have toggleClass working on one of the buttons now)
6. This probably goes without saying, but if all sports buttons are clicked, show all sports.

Here is the code from [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zw813mpq/5/).

```
<button type="button" class="ncaabfilter btn btn-xs btn-default">NCAAB</button> <button type="button" class="ncaaffilter btn btn-xs btn-default">NCAAF</button> <button type="button" class="nbafilter btn btn-xs btn-default">NBA</button> <button type="button" class="nflfilter btn btn-xs btn-default">NFL</button>
<div class="ncaaf">
  NCAAF Game 1
</div>
<div class="nfl">
  NFL Game 1
</div>
<div class="nba">
  NBA Game 1
</div>
<div class="ncaab">
  NCAAB Game 1
</div>
<div class="ncaaf">
  NCAAF Game 2
</div>
<div class="nfl">
  NFL Game 2
</div>
<div class="nba">
  NBA Game 2
</div>
<div class="ncaab">
  NCAAB Game 2
</div>
```

```
$('.ncaabfilter').click(function(){
    $('.ncaaf, .nfl, .nba').toggle(800);

    var isVisible = $('.ncaaf, .nfl, .nba').is(':visible');
    localStorage.setItem('visible', isVisible);
    $('.ncaabfilter').toggleClass('btn-default btn-danger');
  });

var isVisible = localStorage.getItem('visible') === 'false' ? false : true;
$('.ncaaf, .nfl, .nba').toggle(isVisible);
```

Really appreciate the help!

Update: selami below points out localStorage wasn't remembering toggled divs because of 800s. I would like an animation, so maybe I have it wait 800s before localStorage is enacted? But also, how do I get localStorage to retain the btn-danger class for toggled buttons when page is refreshed?

Comment: You have not mentioned as on click of other buttons which text should be displayed?

Comment: @VPK sorry, I thought it was implicit. E.G. If you click NCCAF, NCAAF divs should show and others hide. If you click NCAAF and NBA, NCAAF and NBA game divs should show and others hide. Etc,

Comment: If all buttons are not clicked, i.e. in GRAY color no divs should display right?

Comment: Sorry, no. Per #2 above, if no buttons are clicked (the default state when a new visitor visits), buttons should be GREY but ALL divs should display. All divs can display when no buttons are toggled (and they're grey) or all buttons are toggled (and they're red). Thank you!

Comment: check the updated fiddle in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`toogle(800)` takes 800ms and :visible property set after this time. So, `var isVisible = $('.ncaaf, .nfl, .nba').is(':visible')` returns true, because it doesn't wait to complete toogle.

Also getItem('visible') **===** 'false' contains 3 equal chars. Remove one of them.

Try the following JS

```
$('.ncaabfilter').click(function(){
    $('.ncaaf, .nfl, .nba').toggle();

    var isVisible = $('.ncaaf, .nfl, .nba').is(':visible');
    localStorage.setItem('visible', isVisible);
    $('.ncaabfilter').toggleClass('btn-default btn-danger');
  });

var isVisible = localStorage.getItem('visible') == 'false' ? false : true;
$('.ncaaf, .nfl, .nba').toggle(isVisible);
```

To use 800 parameters for toggle, use callback parameter. Callback function to be executed after the toggle() method is completed.

```
$('.ncaabfilter').click(function(){
  $('.ncaaf, .nfl, .nba').toggle(800, function () { 
    var isVisible = $('.ncaaf, .nfl, .nba').is(':visible');
    localStorage.setItem('visible', isVisible);
  });
  $('.ncaabfilter').toggleClass('btn-default btn-danger');
});
```

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zw813mpq/92/) with 800 animation

Comment: Thank you, the 800ms solves the localStorage not working. However, localStorage isn't remembering that the toggled button should be class btn-danger when page is refreshed. Also, the much larger question I have is how to get all these buttons to work together. Thank you!

Comment: Also, I would like to keep the 800s for animation. What can I do to still include it? Thanks.

Comment: If isVisible is true, add btn-danger class to the button at the end of JS.

Comment: How do I use this current code but also keep the 800ms animation? Can I have it "wait for 800s" before executing the rest of the function? Thank you.

Comment: callback has callback parameters. Callback function to be executed after the toggle() method is completed. set isVisible attribute on callback function. I edit my anwer @iamse7en

Comment: Okay, that fixed local storage, but now the button isn't toggling to RED when I click it.  https://jsfiddle.net/zw813mpq/88/ Thank you

Comment: I don't see any problem. In your fiddle, after toogle function, the color of .ncaabfilter button is red.

Comment: Sorry, I added the wrong link. This fiddle, the button doesn't turn red anymore. localStorage does work tho https://jsfiddle.net/zw813mpq/91/

Comment: Actually, if I move `$('.ncaabfilter').toggleClass('btn-default btn-danger');` outside of the `toggle(function()...` but still in the `click(function()...` it now works. https://jsfiddle.net/zw813mpq/92/ thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need the localStorage just modify the js code like,

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    var button = $(this);
    var contents = button.text().trim().toLowerCase();
    if (button.hasClass('btn-danger')) {
        $('.' + contents).hide(800);
    } else {
        $('.' + contents).show(800);
    }
    $('.'+ contents +'filter').toggleClass('btn-default btn-danger');
});
```

Here's [Working FIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/go4vaibhav/zw813mpq/28/)

I hope it's working as you have expected, with this you don't have to remove the animation, if not let me know. Don't need to add the class `data` for the `divs`. Also I think it would be better if you keep the class `btn-danger` for buttons by default as it would suggest that all options are visible.

**Update to Remember button state**

If you want to remember the state of selected buttons in localStorage, check this [Example to remember state](https://jsfiddle.net/go4vaibhav/zw813mpq/74/). For this you have to add the `id` attribute for the buttons which be used as key for each button in localStorage. The button selected state will be hold as value for these keys.

[Updated fiddle 3](https://jsfiddle.net/go4vaibhav/zw813mpq/57/)

Comment: One issue is, I wanted the default (when someone makes their first visit) to be grey buttons showing all divs. All divs are shown either when all buttons are grey (default) or all red (after each one has been toggled). Is this possible? Also, the 2nd fiddle with localStorage is not working for me. Every time I refresh, it still defaults to all buttons being red with all divs shown. Thank you!

Comment: Suppose your user comes for the first time to this page where all buttons are deselected and all divs are shown, if he/she selects any button then what should happen? What I thought was when button is RED display div and when button is GRAY hide div.. With this rule it is working perfectly fine in second fiddle. If still you want behavior specified by you I'll try.. but I think it is inconsistent behavior as user will confuse the meaning of RED and GRAY buttons..

Comment: The way I think about it is: the default state is using no filtering options. I can see how it is inconsistent, but it's better than having all the buttons lit up  red (indicating they have been selected) or having them begin as hidden. If you wouldn't mind trying to have the default state be gray buttons and visible divs. ALSO: localstorage does not work in the second fiddle. I refresh, but state (buttons I clicked) is forgotten.

Comment: The more I think about it, I'm going to have to go about this in a new way. Especially when filters will conflict with each other. If you can just try to figure out why localStorage isn't working, that would be great. Leave the default state with hidden divs as is, don't worry about changing that. This will be very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Check the `Updated fiddle 3`, here I have tried to implement the specified behavior and fixed the localStorage problem. If you want my second fiddle behavior with working localStorage I will modify that too.

Comment: Hi @iamse7en, sorry the second link was not working correctly with localStorage, I've modified it again check link `Example to remember state` in my answer.

Comment: Your updated fiddle 3 has weird behavior. Clicking button turns it RED but nothing hides. Clicking again turns back to GRAY which causes the sport's divs I clicked to disappear for a second then just re-appear. Clicking the first time should make it turn RED and all OTHER sports hide. If I click a second sport, then just that sport's divs should be unhidden, etc. Thank you!